# Implements an interface that return a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I saw these:

- [Java generics interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568533/java-generics-interface-implementation)
- [java method generics implementing interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637819/java-method-generics-implementing-interface)

I do understand why the compilator complains.

Anyway, if we only use the generic as a return value.

```
public interface Connection 
{
   <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T getVersion();
}
```

Then this implementation only gives a warning (I am using Java 7):

```
public class IoConnectionStub implements Connection
{
   public String getVersion()
   {
      return "1.0";
   }
}
```

Is this valid ? Or will it cause some problems ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have implemented a raw type method of that Interface

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: The interface isn't generic to start with - it's a generic *method*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a generic method, the *caller* can specify the type argument - so I should be able to use:

```
Connection foo = new IoConnectionStub();
Integer x = foo.<Integer>getVersion();
```

That's clearly not going to work in your case.

It sounds like if you really need this (which I think is slightly odd for a version property...) you would want to make the interface generic - that way `IoConnectionStub` could implement `Connection<String>` for example, and you'd end up with code of:

```
Connection<String> foo = new IoConnectionStub();
String version = foo.getVersion();
```

You couldn't *ask* for an `Integer` version number, because `IoConnectionStub` wouldn't implement `Connection<Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it throws a ClassCastException at runtime if the caller ask for the "wrong type". I wonder why the compiler let it go because String does not implement Comparable<? super T> but Comparable<String>. Type erasure?

Comment: @PeeWee2201: When the `T` is `String`, it *does* implement `Comparable<? super T>` because it implements `Comparable<String>`.